# Is there an appropriate name of the following symbol?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, notation, terminology

I have a variable $v$ in an iterating method. I impose an $\delta$ to its value like below.
$$
\begin{equation}
v = \left\{
  \begin{array}{rl}
    v & \text{if } v \geq \delta,\\
    \delta & \text{if } v < \delta.
  \end{array}
  \right.
\end{equation}
$$

How do i call $\delta$? How do I describe this?

Comment: A floor, maybe?

Comment: In computer graphics, we say you *clamp* $v$ to the lower bound $\delta$. I don't think this terminology is common in other fields.

Comment: You are setting $v := \max(v,\delta)$.

Comment: @OscarLanzi I think you mean ceil if any thing. that or max as has been pointed out the symbol $\delta$ is a lower case delta.

Comment: Meant $\delta$ was a floor for $v$.